# Calling two methods on one string variable in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, methods

I'm going through some old VB code and I needed to make a string uppercase. However, it already had a trim function called on it like so,

```
t.Item2 = c.Trim
```

In order to keep the trim function and also make it uppercase I modified the line to

```
t.Item2 = c.Trim.ToUpper
```

Visual Studio didn't throw any errors in the editor when I made this edit and the build didn't fail but I was wondering if I could just stack multiple string methods on the end of the variable? Is there some limit to the amount of methods I could attach to this variable? Is this kosher in practice?

Comment: This is perfectly fine, in my opinion. That said I wouldn't go mad with throwing loads together. I've never found a reason for that.

Comment: If you are finding yourself constantly cleaning your data, wouldnt it be a good idea to do this in the first place. Is this data stored somewhere? If so is the data cleaned the way you need it when saved? If not start now, theres no reason you cant perform any string function or method together with another. This is a opinion in itself...

Comment: Think about what's actually happening here.  Your `c` variable is type `String`.  You call the `Trim` method of that `String`.  What does `Trim` return?  It returns a `String`, right?  So, you're simply calling `ToUpper` on that `String`; NOT the original one.  A `String` reference is a `String` reference regardless of where it comes from and you can call `ToUpper` on any `String` reference.